# How to correct this error in ionic framwork cordova application?

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, google-plus, google-play-services

when i run my application ionic corodva in the real device

i found this error :

```
:processDebugManifest/home/m2tech1/Bureau/Copy of ElolinkProject/platforms/android/AndroidManifest.xml:14:66 Error:
    Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=(4452000) from AndroidManifest.xml:14:66
    is also present at com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0:23:13 value=(@integer/google_play_services_version)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:9 to override
 FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#com.google.android.gms.version@value value=(4452000) from AndroidManifest.xml:14:66
    is also present at com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:8.3.0:23:13 value=(@integer/google_play_services_version)
    Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:9 to override

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.62 secs

/home/m2tech1/Bureau/Copy of ElolinkProject/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: /home/m2tech1/Bureau/Copy of ElolinkProject/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/m2tech1/Bureau/Copy of ElolinkProject/platforms/android/build.gradle,-PcdvBuildArch=arm,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
ERROR running one or more of the platforms: Error: /home/m2tech1/Bureau/Copy of ElolinkProject/platforms/android/cordova/run: Command failed with exit code 8
```

please hel me

Comment: Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to <meta-data> element at AndroidManifest.xml:14:9 to override , have u tried to replace the android api lvl already?

Comment: thanks for your response  but your suggestion is related with native android developpment. Actually, I develop an hybride application.

Comment: Hi, even it's hybrid it's still partial android. Try it see whether it works.